# Postgres 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

[image: pgadmin 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip']

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

I deleted FKs and PKs. Pgadmin has stopped working properly. The tables with which FK and PK are related don't work either. Nothing is deleted. And the data is not showing. How can I fix?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide steps to reproduce the problem (a [mre])? See [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: Honest question: what should one do if an error is idiosyncratic and/or clearly irreproducible? For instance, this question is asking about a NoneType error which likely has to do with the app itself (programming language) and not OP's database or query. I've found this site to be unusually difficult to use lately due to MRE expectations. I don't fault anyone for asking, but I wish users had a way to flag our questions as having no MRE. Another issue is that it's OFTEN easier to completely change your stack than it is to completely redact your codebase in order to jump through the MRE hoop.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error today. I did some silly things and renamed table copies I was generating during texting. Adding a prefix of x,y & z as I went.
Deleting in PG Admin 4.6 from the right-click menu produced this error.
Using

```
    Drop Table schema.name
```

did delete without any error.